# How to justify form input fields with css?

Tags: html, css, forms, layout

I have a simple signup input form (haml for brevity here:)

```
%form#signup
  %fieldset
    %input.email{type:'text'}
    %br
    .name
      %input.first-name{type:'text'}
      %input.last-name{type:'text'}
```

and css:

```
#signup { width: 350px; }
fieldset { width: 100%; }
.name { width: 100%; }
.first-name { width: 30%; }
.last-name { /* occupy remainder of 'name' line */ }
```

How to style this so that the `.email` field is the full width of the `fieldset` and the `.last-name` and/or `.first-name` fields expand to also fill the entire width of the `fieldset` and with the right edge aligned with the `.email` field?

Yes it might be easier to use a `table` here but is there a simple way with css?   It need only work for css3 compliant browsers and degrade reasonably for IE8 and 9.

fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/3UP9H/1

Comment: Show your *real* HTML and, ideally, post a link to a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: ok, http://jsfiddle.net/3UP9H/1    notice that the .email field extends outside of the fieldset border (on chrome anyway.) the goal is to simply right-justify each line of the fieldset by expanding the input fields to full width. your solution?

Comment: Are you okay with absolute, rather than relative, units? Since you're explicitly identifying `350px` for the `form` itself?

Comment: the fieldset width is arbitrary but ideally the elements should use only relative measures so as not to hardcode the sizes throughout.

Answer (score 3):

Original answer appears below the `hr`; the answer to the question, for clarity, appears to be a combination of `box-sizing` (and its vendor-previxed variants), in order to include the `border-width` and `padding` in the defined `width` of the elements(s) (rather than their width being defined-width + border-width + padding) and `font-size: 0` for the parent element, which removes the errant space between the two `input` elements (although the space is, technically, still there; it just doesn't have any size to influence the position of the surrounding elements).

So, the CSS is that from the second example below:

```
fieldset input[type=text] {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 350px;
}

fieldset div input[type=text] {
    width: 105px;
    margin: 0;
}

fieldset div input[type=text] + input[type=text] {
    float: right;
    width: 245px;
}

div.name {
    font-size: 0;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3UP9H/11/).

---

#### Original answer follows:

One way seems to be:

```
form {
    width: 350px;
}

fieldset {
    width: 100%;
}

​fieldset input[type=text] {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 350px;
}​​

fieldset div input[type=text] {
    width: 105px;
    margin: 0;
}

fieldset div input[type=text] + input[type=text] {
    float: right;
    width: 241px;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3UP9H/7/).

The use of `box-sizing` (and the vendor-prefixed variants) is to simply include the `border` of the element, and any assigned `padding` within the defined width of the element.

I've used self-closing `input` tags in the linked demo, since `input` elements, so far as I know, don't have closing tags `</input>`.

I've amended the above, slightly, to remove the issue of the errant space (between the sibling `input` elements in the `.name` element from requiring arbitrary corrections to allow them both on the same line (hence the strange `width: 241px` in the above CSS):

```
form {
    width: 350px;
}

fieldset {
    width: 100%;
}

fieldset input[type=text] {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 350px;
}

fieldset div input[type=text] {
    width: 105px;
    margin: 0;
}

fieldset div input[type=text] + input[type=text] {
    float: right;
    width: 245px;
}

div.name {
    font-size: 0;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3UP9H/8/).

---

**Edited** to remove the fixed-width measurements, and replaced with relative, percentage, based units (as in the original question):

```
form {
    width: 350px;
}

fieldset {
    width: 100%;
}

fieldset input[type=text] {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

fieldset div input[type=text] {
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0;
}

fieldset div input[type=text] + input[type=text] {
    float: right;
    width: 70%;
}

div.name {
    font-size: 0;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3UP9H/9/).

Unfortunately there's no way to set the width of the `input` elements to `100%` by default, while still allowing sibling `input` elements to have differing widths. Or, there is, but it's substantially more awkward and requires you to explicitly identify both siblings as, although it's possible to select the second, or later, sibling with the `+` or `~` combinators it's not possible to select the *first* sibling based on its having subsequent siblings (without JavaScript, or other scripting language, whether client-, or server-, side).

Comment: interesting. i'll look at box-sizing. the inline-block is extraneous.

Comment: As to the `inline-block`: *agreed*.

Comment: not concerned with the selectors generally, just the box-sizing to make the fields align. if you pare down your answer to just the second edit/demo i'll accept it.  @saluce was on the right track with this too.  thanks guys!

Comment: I've edited to clarify, but I prefer not to remove information from an answer (unless it's clearly wrong), on the off-chance that there might be something useful to someone else in the progression/development.

Comment: too much extraneous to wade through. i'd prefer to see only the first paragraph and the last code sample.  less is more. the one line answer is, use the css attribute `box-sizing` to rectify the `input` field rendering across browsers.

Answer (score 0):

```
#signup { width: 350px; }
fieldset { width: 100%; border: 1px solid grey; padding:2px;}
.email { width: 99%;margin-bottom:2px; }
.name { width: 100%; }
.first-name { width: 30%; }
.last-name { width : 67% }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3UP9H/4/)

**Update**

```
#signup { width: 350px; }
fieldset { width: 100%; border: 1px solid grey; padding:2px;}
.email { width: 99%;margin-bottom:2px; }
.name { width: 100%; }
.first-name { width: 30%; }
.last-name { width : 67%; float:right; }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3UP9H/6/)

Firefox Screenshot.

[image]

Comment: that doesn't work in FF. i'm looking for something principled, i.e. the css says 'expand these elements to be right justified' generally rather than something ad-hoc that just happens to work (or not) for the example.

Comment: nope. last-name field is skipped to another line. it's not about tweaking the percentages. it needs to line up exactly to the pixel, regardless of the width of the fieldset, font-size, border decoration, etc. (or at least for a given border decoration.)

Comment: @Sheikh I saw the same problem in FF13

Answer (score 0):

Change these two lines to look like this:

```
.email { width: 99%; float: right; }
.last-name { width: 65%; float: right;}​
```

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/3UP9H/5/)

**EDIT** The odd thing is that about `width` in Chrome and IE is that there is an extra 4px width that isn't there in Firefox.  The problem is that Chrome and IE add the border to the width of the box, while Firefox compensates the width of the internal textfield to make it fit the border within the bounds specified.  See [this version of the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SapWq/) for a demonstration.

**EDIT2** Check this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SapWq/6/).

Comment: again, that's a kind of ad-hoc solution and now the left edge is not aligned. put the `border: 1px solid grey` back on the `fieldset` to see  this.   probably the solution is more involved than tweaking the percentages. also the first-name width is arbitrary, just for example. the question is simply right (and left) justify each line of input fields within the fieldset. any css experts ?

Comment: ok, this is close, http://jsfiddle.net/SapWq/2/  but as you say now has the extra margin in ff.  is there a way to do it without a special case for moz ?