# Make 2 HTML input fields same width as the one on top

Tags: html, css, forms

Please see [this little HTML form](http://jsfiddle.net/HSkyq/)

I'd like to have ZIP & city input fields on one line, but on the right have the city input field end with the name input field on one line.

How could I do that? Thanks.

Comment: adjusting manually the input width is an option?

Comment: can you describe more exact what your looking for?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to justify form input fields with css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965155/how-to-justify-form-input-fields-with-css)

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**
http://jsfiddle.net/wMUAK/

CSS

```
label {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 2px;
}

.c1 {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}

.c2 {
    float: left;
    width: 40px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.c3 {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
}

.c1 input[type=text],
.c2 input[type=text],
.c3 input[type=text] {
    width: 100%;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

HTML
    Name
    
      
    
    
    ZIP and city

**Solution 2:**
http://jsfiddle.net/HSkyq/5/

CSS

```
.table {
    display: table;
}

.table .row {
    display: table-row;
}

.table .cell {
    display: table-cell;
}

.group {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.group .gcell {
    display: table-cell;
}

.table input {
    width: 100%;
}​
```

HTML

```
<div class="table" style="width: 300px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell" style="width:40%;">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      <label for="city">ZIP and city</label>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="group">
        <div class="gcell" style="width: 40%;">
          <input type="text" name="zip" style="width: 90%;" />
        </div>
        <div class="gcell">
          <input type="text" name="city" id="city" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>​
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but this looks even worse than creating a HTML-table... I hope there is another solution

Comment: ok i added a second solution.

Comment: Thanks again. However, I've found some other solutions in links shown here that look a little more elegant... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965155/how-to-justify-form-input-fields-with-css?rq=1

Comment: more elegant? :D ok gr8 you should have made your research before posting a duplicate question. you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Now check the result, the link is as follows - http://jsfiddle.net/HSkyq/4/