# text fields to be left justified and numbers should be right justified

Tags: html, css

My requirement is all text fields in my page should left justified and number fields sholud right justified. Is there any css to accomplish this

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to justify form input fields with css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965155/how-to-justify-form-input-fields-with-css)

Answer (score 2):

```
input[type='text']{text-align: left;}
input[type='number']{text-align: right;}
```

Comment: sorry bro, didn't mean to snipe you. is it cool if i link your fiddle? (giving you the credit of course)